# Sublime Text 2 Key Bindings - Is there any way to detect left/right modifier keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, modifier-keys

Is it possible to make <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> do different things? And of course, other modifier keys.

If not, maybe the following idea would work? 
If AppleScript, Python, Ruby, Perl etc. can detect left/right modifiers I can set complicated key bindings in sublime text (like ["cmd+ctrl+shift+alt+a", "cmd+ctrl+shift+alt+a"]) and send those keystrokes with AppleScript or Automator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remap the key combinations with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <appdef>
        <appname>SUBLIMETEXT</appname>
        <equal>com.sublimetext.2</equal>
    </appdef>
    <item>
        <name>test</name>
        <identifier>test</identifier>
        <only>SUBLIMETEXT</only>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::OPTION_R, KeyCode::F19</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

Or just change modifier keys:

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>`

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).